# convert a char to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

my code works great until know and, if I put a double digit number into the text field (like 12) nslog returns 2 single digit numbers (like 1 and 2). Now I need to put these 2 single digit numbers into 2  strings. can somebody help me. thanks in advance.

```
    NSString *depositOverTotalRwy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [deposit text]];
NSArray *components = [depositOverTotalRwy
                       componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *firstThird = [components objectAtIndex:0];
  for(int i = 0; i < [firstThird length]; i++)
{
   char extractedChar = [firstThird characterAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"%c", extractedChar);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `-stringWithFormat:`.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", extractedChar];
```

EDIT:

You can store them in an array.

```
NSMutableArray *digits = [NSMutableArray array];

for ( int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++ ) {
    char extractedChar = [s characterAtIndex:i];

    [digits addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", extractedChar]];
}
```

Comment: yes it works but doing this I get both digit in the same string. what about if I want to split it into 2 strings? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to print the value of **firstThird** using `NSLog()`, see what it exactly hold, you code seem correct,

Use `characterAtIndex` function for `NSString` to extract a character at known location

```
   - (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Use as below

```
NSString *FirstDigit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:0]];
NSString *SecondDigit  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:1]];
```